# how to prove correctness of algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, induction

I'm required to do a correctness proof using induction on this function:

```
def FUNCTION(n):
    if n>94:
        return n-8
    else:
        return FUNCTION(FUNCTION(n+9))
```

where n <= 94

Basically, this function always returns 87 if the input is less than or equal 94, and I need to prove that using inductive proof. I have no idea where to start, can someone help? like what the base case here might be like or what to assume in the inductive hypothesis.

Comment: Are there any bounds on the input variable n and the return variable of the function and what are the consequences if those bounds are breeched?

Comment: the bounds is that n have to be less than or equal 94, if the input was more than 94 then it will just return then input - 8

Answer (score 0):

For convenience, I will use $f$ instead of FUNCTION. I use the notation $f(x) \to y$ to indicate that $f(x)$ partially or fully simplifies to $y$.

Theorem: for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $f(95 - n) \to 87$.

Proof: we proceed by strong induction on $n$.

Base case: $n = 0$. Then $f(95 - n)$ is just $f(95)$. Since $95 > 94$, we see that $f(95 - n)$ evaluates to $87$.

Strong inductive step: let $n = k + 1$. Then $95 - n = 94 - k \leq 94$. Then $f(95 - n) = f(94 - k) \to f(f(94 - k + 9))$.

Case 1: $k < 9$. Then $94 - k + 9 = 94 + (9 - k) > 94$, so $f(94 - k + 9) \to 94 - k + 1 = 95 - k$. Then $f(f(94 - k + 9)) \to f(95 - k) \to 87$ by the strong inductive hypothesis.

Case 2: $k \geq 9$. Then $94 - k + 9 = 95 - (k - 8)$, and $k - 8 \leq k$. Then by the strong inductive hypothesis, we have $f(94 -k + 9) = f(95 - (k - 8)) \to 87$.  Thus, we have $f(f(94 - k + 9)) \to f(87) = f(94 - 7)$. Since $7 \leq k$, we see that by the strong inductive hypothesis, $f(94 - 7) \to 87$.

Thus, we see that for all natural numbers $n$, we have $f(95 - n) \to 87$. Then we see that for all integers $n \leq 95$, we have $f(n) \to 87$.